# Data set not valid

Tags: google-cloud-platform, data-annotations, google-cloud-automl

title=Could not perform action, message=Could not perform requested action, verify that the inputs are valid., detail=com.google.api.gax.rpc.FailedPreconditionException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: To start training the model, it requires each annotation spec has 8 annotations for training, 1 annotations for validation and 1 annotations for testing. Current dataset does not meet the minimum requirement. Please import more data with those annotation specs before training:[2, 4, 1].
Any clues, dataset matches all the criteria given at google cloud AUTOML documentation

Comment: can you please provide with a screenshot of your [Dasets > 'yourdataset' > LABEL STATS] page? (just of the table that appears here https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/label#view_label_statistics)